# Is there an option to do getBulk from cache with spring cache

Tags: memcached, spring-cache, spymemcached

I'm using Spring's [caching](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html) abstraction in my application and the underlying cache is memcached.

memcached supports bulk lookup from cache by providing a collection of keys. see getBulk() [javadoc here](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/unzip/unzip/spy/spymemcached/2.8.0/spymemcached-2.8.0-javadoc.jar-unzip/net/spy/memcached/MemcachedClient.html)

However spring cache interface doesn't allow bulk lookup ? Is there a specific reason or are there ways to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache API is a base model to help us provide declarative caching, it is not meant to abstract every possible use of caching.

Each cache implementation has a `getNativeCache` that returns the underlying library implementation. If you need access to a library specific feature, that's what you should use.